# AngularJS - Create dynamic controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have some app build with jQuery, and now I want to use angularjs to do some magic with my app.

What's doing my current app? 
1st.  - It creates some DOM elements using jquery :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"></div> 
        <script>
            for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                var $elem = $('<div>')
                    .attr('id', 'box-' + i)
                    .appendTo('#wrapper');

            } 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, i make some AJAX call, and basing on the returned JSON i know, that i want to create some new DOM element ( By jquery and handlebars ),  and append it to $("#elem-2");

```
$.get('something', function(response){
    var elemInstance = new MyElement(response); //function MyElement handles my object creation based on the response.
    var $elem = elemInstance.render(); //return new jQuery Object, like: return $("<div>");
    $elem.appendTo('#wrapper #box-2');
});
```

This works great, but because this dynamically created $elem  and its "contoller" ( MyElement ) are very complex and needs to rerended often i would love to use angular to controll all element created this way.

So, the question is:
Can I have something like class in OOP in angular and create new object basing on this class?
Can I create angular controller in runtime? Or maybe ma approch is totaly wrong?